# jQuery ajax call to webservice to retrieve bitmap errors with code 200

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wcf, web-services

**EDIT** code updated

when I removed dataType it call success. however, the image does not get displayed (instead a placeholder X for an image tag is displayed). Is it even possible to display the bytes of an image in a html image tag?

**original**

With the following snippet (config seems to be fine) I am trying to experiment to see if I can get bitmap data from the server and load it into the DOM. The problem is it is the ajax call gets an error but the status code is 200 "OK"... does anyone know why?

Default.aspx (test page)

```
<div></div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    /// <reference path="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5-vsdoc.js"/>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Service.svc/GetBitmap",
            context: $("<div>"),
            success: function (r) {
                $(this).append(
                   $("<img src='data:image/bmp;base64," + r.text+ "'></img>"));
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Service.cs (test service)

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public byte[] GetBitmap()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Bitmap/test.bmp"));
        b.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        return new BinaryReader(ms).ReadBytes((int)ms.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried without the `base64,` part?

Comment: @Einacio: yes, I have. the bitmap is valid, too, when I use <img src="Bitmap/test.bmp" /> it displays properly

Comment: and the inverse, base64 encoding the service return?

Comment: @Einacio: I was assuming WCF was doing that for me, perhaps wrongfully. Do I have to do something special on the service side?

Comment: i don't know WCF, that's why i just posted as a suggestion. You'd better research and prove me wrong. try putting the ajax answer inside a `<pre>` and you'll see if it's base64 encoded

Comment: I ended up getting it to work, not really sure how but perhaps my img tag was formatted wrong. It was in base64. perhaps i forgot the data: part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the correct MIME type is `image/bmp`, not `img/bmp`.

That said, as far as I know `$.ajax` only supports text data types. See here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

I would suggest you to write a service that returns the image via a well-known URL.

Comment: I updated the question to what it originally should have been. If I cannot figure it out I will accept this as the solution because it helped me get this far.